# Can you install puppet without ruby 1.8?

Tags: puppet, ruby

I need to install puppet 3.2.0 or greater along with ruby 2.0.0-p247 on an ubuntu 12.04 server.

**Is there no way to install puppet *without* ruby 1.8?**

---

Most my experience comes from CentOS so I may be missing something simple with apt.

**My setup:**

Make sure no ruby is present

```
root@gitlab:~# which ruby
root@gitlab:~# ruby --version
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

Install puppet from the official ppa

```
root@gitlab:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs.list

deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com precise main  
deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com precise main  

deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com precise dependencies  
deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com precise dependencies
```

The latest version of puppet is listed in apt

```
root@gitlab:~# apt-cache policy puppet|head
puppet:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.3.0-1puppetlabs1
  Version table:
     3.3.0-1puppetlabs1 0
        500 http://apt.puppetlabs.com/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.4-1puppetlabs1 0
        500 http://apt.puppetlabs.com/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.3-1puppetlabs1 0
        500 http://apt.puppetlabs.com/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Installing puppet 3.3.0 brings ruby 1.8 along automatically.

```
 root@gitlab:~# apt-get install puppet-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  augeas-lenses debconf-utils facter hiera libaugeas-ruby libaugeas-ruby1.8 libaugeas0 libjson-ruby libruby libruby1.8
  libshadow-ruby1.8 ruby ruby-json ruby-rgen ruby1.8 virt-what
Suggested packages:
  augeas-doc augeas-tools ruby-selinux libselinux-ruby1.8 librrd-ruby1.9.1 librrd-ruby1.8 ri ruby-dev ruby1.8-examples ri1.8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  augeas-lenses debconf-utils facter hiera libaugeas-ruby libaugeas-ruby1.8 libaugeas0 libjson-ruby libruby libruby1.8
  libshadow-ruby1.8 puppet-common ruby ruby-json ruby-rgen ruby1.8 virt-what
0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 92 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,664 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

puppet version

```
root@gitlab:/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247# puppet --version
3.3.0
```

ruby version

```
root@gitlab:/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247# ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

(note that ruby is automatically installed via update alternatives)

```
root@gitlab:/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247# ll `which ruby`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Sep 18 02:57 /usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby*


root@gitlab:/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247# update-alternatives --list ruby
/usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

I then install ruby 2.0 into it's own directory, from source

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/ruby2.0
```

Then register ruby 2.0 with update-alternatives

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.0/bin/ruby 10
```

Switch to ruby 2.0 via update-alternatives

```
    root@gitlab:/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247# update-alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.0/bin/ruby
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ruby2.0/bin/ruby to provide /usr/bin/ruby (ruby) in manual mode.
root@gitlab:/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247# ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

I've done this several times, as long as `which ruby` points to any version of ruby other than 1.8, puppet returns the following error:

```
root@gitlab:/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247# puppet --version
/usr/bin/ruby2.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- puppet/util/command_line (LoadError)
    from /usr/bin/ruby2.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/puppet:3:in `<main>'
```

**How can I get puppet installed with ruby 2.0?**

---

Puppet 3.3 is compatible with ruby 2.0 because it is listed on [puppet's website](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/platforms.html)

Additional resources

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/18494

RVM appears to be far more complex than what I need. Also, the faq's say not to use it with sudo, or run it as root which I must do. 
https://rvm.io/
http://rvm.io/support/faq

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892877/how-do-i-make-ruby-1-9-the-default-ruby-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to install ruby 2.0 and puppet 3.3.0 by using rvm

1. Install puppet

   apt-get install puppet
2. Install rvm

   \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
3. Logout and log back in
4. Install ruby 2.0

   rvm install ruby 2.0.0-p247
5. Switch to ruby 2.0

   rvm use 2.0.0-p247

Comment: Truth. RVM is currently the only way to get Ruby 2 onto an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `$ apt-cache depends puppet`; you might be able to use `ruby-1.9`, but as of 2013-09-17 at least, [ruby 2.0 has not been packaged in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ruby).

Answer (score 0):

The packaged version requires ruby 1.8 or 1.9. You can use one of the not recommended methods to install it (gem, tarball), e.g., `sudo gem install puppet`.